# Retrieve the location of files and pick one to play audio

Tags: java, android, audio, file-io

I am interested in playing a sound file (extension either .wav or .mp3) in a directory using "AudioTrack". Only thing I want to know is the file name and its path. What is the best option for such problem?

I put several .wav files in res/raw folder, named
wav1.wav, wav2.wav, wav3.wav, wav4.wav

I need a function looks like this :

```
private String FileFullpath (String path) {
    Random R = new Random();
    String filefullpath;
    int iPick;
    File f = new File(path);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    iPick = R.nextInt(files.length);
    filefullpath = files[iPick] /// something like C:/Music/wav3.wav ?
    return filefullpath;
}
```

Then I can pick one file random in a folder and play it

....

```
String filefullpath = FileFullpath("res/raw"); // pick one sound file
PlayWavFileViaAudioTrack(filefullpath);    // play the chosen sound file
```

Or the second option, how can I move my files to the internal storage?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably need a random number and get files within a range to get a file based on it.

Comment: Well, I pick a random number among the number of files read from the directory by using R.nextInt